# Blood transfer during airplane scene

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

In the beginning of The Dark Knight Rises, Bane and his minions take over the airplane in which Dr. Pavel is transported. After having the control over the airplane, and having it wired up with cables, they bring in a body bag in which a seemingly dead person lies in. Then, they start a blood transfer with Dr. Pavel.

But why? I guess they want, when the bodies are found, the body-bag-person will be identified as Pavel. I am sure that this little blood would not be enough, it only took some seconds. Is there any other reason or explanation?

Comment: I think the pretty much was the reason, yes (they also later say that (they think) Pavel died in a plane crash, so it apparently worked). However, I don't think spending too much thought on how realistic that was is too fruitful, since yes, that was likely not enough to make a corpose look like someone totally different.